# Letters not typing in online code editors and graphing calculators

Tags: windows-10

*Hi, I have a following problem in Windows 10 OS at DELL Inspirion 14 pc:
the letters are typing fine when accessing all standard text input controls, but I have problems when using **online code editors** like codepen.io or **online graphing calculators** like Desmos. The letters stop typing most often when I navigate through mathematical expressions or just randomly when writing code. Using keyboard arrows sometimes prevents the problem from occuring. The issue occurs at Google Chrome browser as well as in Microsoft Edge...

Comment: Have you tried updating the drivers required for the keyboard?

Comment: I'll try in the evening, and update the question if there will still be issues